# Show selected option value in a div

Tags: jquery, html, append

I want to insert into `#example` div new radio button when I select from option box. This is my code but when I select a value it is not working. I cant see anything on screen. Where is the problem?

```
<select id="keys">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

<script>
  var selectedKey = $("#keys").val();
  $('#example').append('<input name='+selectedKey+' class="ace-checkbox-2" type="checkbox"><span class="lbl">'+selectedKey+'&nbsp;</span>');                            
</script>

<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: See my 2nd example.(additionaly how can I delete inserted <input.. if I change my idea after I add? )

Comment: @samitha where is the example about delete operation. I could not see anything sorry :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BbvvE/1/ do you need this ?

Comment: @samitha no no answer is JOHN's answer. You can see below. But also I want to add discart ink or button near to <input name..> when user click to discart <input element must delete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script does not handle `keys` selection change in any way. It shoud be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#keys").change(function(){
        var selectedKey = $(this).val();
        $('#example').append('<input name='+selectedKey+' class="ace-checkbox-2" type="checkbox"><span class="lbl">'+selectedKey+'&nbsp;</span>');    
    });
});
```

Comment: ok now, it is working. additionaly how can I delete inserted <input.. if I change my idea after I add?

Comment: `$('#example').empty()` just after `var selectedKey = $(this).val();`. But isn't it simpler in this case to restructure app to always have an input in `example`?

Comment: no, I want to delete only clicked element. I will set a link near to my input element. If user click remove link input element must deleted

Answer (score 1):

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BbvvE/)

Jquery

```
 $("#keys").change(function(){
var selectedKey = $("#keys").val();
 $('#example').append('<input name=' + selectedKey + ' class="ace-checkbox-2" type="checkbox"><span class="lbl">' + selectedKey + '&nbsp;</span>');
```

});

But above code appending check box to that div.So if you want only the selected check box to show inside the example div Use bellow one

```
 $("#keys").change(function(){
var selectedKey = $("#keys").val();
 $('#example').html('<input name=' + selectedKey + ' class="ace-checkbox-2" type="checkbox"><span class="lbl">' + selectedKey + '&nbsp;</span>');

 });
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BbvvE/1/)

Comment: your first code part is my answer but now I want to add discart button or link near to <input> element. When I click discart <input> element must remove